# LinAlgError: SVD did not converge in Linear Least Squares while plotting a trendline?

Tags: csv, trendline

While using the code below, im trying to create a trendline. The scattergraph works but is keep getting the error:"LinAlgError: SVD did not converge in Linear Least Squares" when i try to work with the trendline. What am i doing wrong?

code:

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from numpy import genfromtxt

data = genfromtxt("som.csv", delimiter=",")

tijd=data[:, 0]

afstand=data[:, 1]

plt.scatter(tijd, afstand)

z = np.polyfit(tijd, afstand, 2)

p = np.poly1d(z)

plt.plot(tijd,p(tijd),"r--")

i used a method that i have used before with similar data, but while it worked in the past it no longer seems to work.